# Getting the error: bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

When I run the command

```bsh
./program
```

I get the error:

```bsh
bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

When I run `uname -a` I get:

```bsh
4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:34:49 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Also I checked the information about the program that I was trying to run and I got:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=c154cb3d21f6bbd505d165aed3aa6ed682729441, not stripped
```

`/proc/cpuinfo` shows

```
flags       : fpuvme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

How can I run the program?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a 64-bit x86 CPU (indicated by the `lm` flag in `/proc/cpuinfo`), but you’re running a 32-bit kernel. The program you’re trying to run requires a 64-bit runtime, so it won’t work as-is: even on a 64-bit CPU, a 32-bit kernel can’t run 64-bit programs.

If you can find a 32-bit build of the program (or build it yourself), use that.

Alternatively, you can install a 64-bit kernel, reboot, and then install the 64-bit libraries required by your program.

To install a 64-bit kernel, run

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic:amd64
```

This will install the latest 64-bit Xenial kernel, along with various supporting 64-bit packages. Once you reboot, you should find that `uname -a` shows `x86_64` rather than `i686`. If you attempt to run your program again, it might just work, or you’ll get an error because of missing libraries; in the latter case, install the corresponding packages (use `apt-file` to find them) to get the program working.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into same issue on Ubuntu Server and got the following error:

`-bash: /usr/bin/my-script: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

I found a general solution for running x86-64 files on arm CPU. Running the following code fixed it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y qemu-user-static binfmt-support
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libc6:amd64
```

Source : https://www.kali.org/docs/arm/x86-on-arm/

Answer (score -2):

You have  a 32-bit CPU (x86) and are trying to run a 64-bit executable (x86_64). You can't run that executable on that CPU. Either find a 32-bit build or compile the source yourself.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is incorrect; the CPU is 64-bit capable, as evidenced by the `lm` flag in `cpuinfo`. Based on the information we have, the OPs problem is 100% a software problem, not hardware.